# Trouble outputting the correct maximum and minimum value from array

Tags: c, arrays, max, min

I've written a program that involves the user choosing a number of days (between 3 and 10) to enter the temperature for and then entering the high and low temperature for each day. The problem I am having is that I have to output the highest high and lowest low temperature among those inputs as well as the day this high and low occurred. My code seems to always jump to the last day even if it does not contain the highest high or the lowest low and the day is always one day greater than the number of days output. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    int i;
    int limit;
    int day[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    int high[10],low[10];

    printf("---===IPC Temperature Analyzer V2.0===---\n");

    printf("Please enter the number of days between 3 and 10, inclusive: ");
    scanf("%d", &limit);
    while (limit <= 2 || limit >= 11) {
            printf("Invalid entry, please enter a number between 3 and 10,   inclusive: ");
            scanf("%d", &limit);
    }

    for(i = 0;i < limit; i++) {
            printf("Day %d - High: ", day[i]);
            scanf("%d", &high[i]);
            printf("Day %d - Low: ", day[i]);
            scanf("%d", &low[i]);
    }

    printf("\nDay Hi Low\n");
    for (i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
            printf("%d   %d    %d\n", day[i], high[i], low[i]);
    }

    int max = 0;
    int min = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
            if (high[max] < high[i])
            max = i;
            if (low[min] < low[i])
            min = i;

    }

    printf("\nHighest temperature was: %d on day %d", high[max], day[max]);

    printf("\nLowest temperature was: %d on day %d ", low[min], day[min]);


    return 0;

}
```

Comment: `if (max < high[i]);` Remove `;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to initialize min and max after you read the input.

```
int max = 0;
int min = 0;

for (i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
   if (high[max] < high[i])
      max = i;

   if (low[min] > low[i])
      low = i;    
}

printf("\nHighest temperature was: %d on day %d", high[max], day[max]);

printf("\nLowest temperature was: %d on day %d ", low[min], day[min]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `;` from line `if (max < high[i]);` and `if (min > low[i]);`

Also you can combine these two loops

```
for (i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
        if (max < high[i])
        max = high[i];
}

printf("\nHighest temperature was: %d on day %d", max, day[i]);

for (i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
        if (min > low[i])
        min = low[i];
}
```

Into one for loop like this

```
for (i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
        if (max < high[i])
            max = high[i]
        if (min > low[i])
            min = low[i];
}
```

Comment: @Bob__ : Fixed :)